# Cayley graphs do not have isolated maximal cliques

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, cayley-graphs

Let a Cayley graph $G$ of a group $H$ with respect to the generating set $\{s_i\}$ have a clique of order $> 2$. In addition assume the graph $G$ is non-complete. If the clique size is less than half the order of $G$, then is it possible for some group $H$ that $G$ has a unique "disjoint maximal clique". By "disjoint maximal clique", I mean a  clique equal to the clique size of the graph, and such that any other clique of same order would not be vertex disjoint with the prior clique.

I don't think so. For, if $(e),(s_1),(s_1\cdot s_2),(s_1\cdot s_2\cdot s_3),\ldots,(s_1\cdot s_2\cdots s_n)$ be the sequence of vertices in a maximal clique, then I think even $(s_1^2),(s_1^3),(s_1^2\cdot s_2),\ldots,(s_1^2\cdot s_2\cdots s_n)$ would also be a sequence of vertices in a maximal clique, where $e$ denotes the identity element. But, what if $s_1$ is an order $2$ or $3$ element. How do we ensure that there always exist a disjoint clique apart from the clique $(e),(s_1),(s_1\cdot s_2),(s_1\cdot s_2\cdot s_3),\ldots,(s_1\cdot s_2\cdots s_n)$? Will this be true at least for the case when $H$ is an abelian/cyclic group? Any hints? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Your question is not clear. "Disjoint" is a property of two things, not a property of one thing.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay edited the post.

Comment: Your terminology looks confusing. "Unique maximal clique" usually means that it is a maximal clique and there is no other maximal clique.

Comment: @FedorPetrov no, my meaning is that there is a maximal clique and no other "vertex disjoint" maximal clique

Comment: Rephrased: "Do all maximal cliques in $G$ pairwise intersect"? (Also I don't see why you need to assume $G$ is non-complete: then your condition is trivially satisfied.)

Comment: @SamHopkins yes, that is my question.( and yes, complete graphs trivially satisfy the condition and hence would not be a problem!-the problem starts when clique number of $G$ is less than half the order of $G$)

Comment: Your definition still seems a bit strange. A disjoint maximal clique is one that is NOT disjoint from any other clique? Is that really what you mean?

Comment: @verret yes, my meaning is  that a disjoint maximal clique is one that is NOT disjoint from any other MAXIMAL clique.

Comment: @verret I think this is related to your paper [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0195669814001516)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G$ be the linegraph of the complete graph $K_n$ for $n\geq 5$. For some but not all $n$, $G$ is a Cayley graph, see Chris Godsil's answer to [another question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/150744/the-line-graphs-of-complete-graphs-and-cayley-graphs).

$G$ has $\binom n2$ vertices and degree $2n-4$. The maximum cliques of $G$ correspond to the edges incident with one vertex and so they have size $n-1$.  Moreover, the cliques corresponding to two different vertices of $K_n$ have one point in common, namely the edge between those two vertices.

Therefore, $G$ is an example of a Cayley graph for which any two maximum cliques intersect, even though the maximum cliques only have size about the square root of the number of vertices.

I wonder if this example is optimal in some sense.

---

ADDED: Here is an exposition of Ilya's argument from the comments.

Theorem. If a vertex-transitive graph with $N$ vertices has cliques of size $k$ such that $k^2<N$, then there are two such cliques which are disjoint.

Proof. Take a fixed $k$-clique $C$ and apply a random automorphism $\gamma$. The expected number of elements of $C$ that map to an element of $C$ is $k^2/N$, so $k^2<N$ implies that $C$ must sometimes map to a clique disjoint from itself.

In the case of a Cayley graph of a group $\varGamma$, we can use a random non-identity element of $\varGamma$ to improve the inequality to $k(k-1)<N-1$.

There is a clique size gap of about $\sqrt 2$ between these bounds and the linegraph of a complete graph. So the problem is still missing a complete solution.

Comment: It is optimal in some sense: if a Cayley graph contains a clique of size $<\sqrt n$, then it contains its isomorphic copy, from probabilistic reasons

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov you mean if a cayley graph has clique size $< \sqrt n$, then it has disjoint cliques of maximal size? Any reference for this?

Comment: If a clique size is $k$, there are $n$ copies of one clique (starting from any vertex), and only $k(k-1)+1$ of them intersects the initial one (any vertex of a copy may coincide with any vertex of the origin).

Comment: will the property hold for cayley graphs on cyclic or abelian groups at least?

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov in saying that there are $n$ cliques of size $k$, you are using the vertex transitivity of the graph, isnt it? So this should hold for vertex transitive graphs also, right?

Comment: Yes, I’m using transitivity. Not exactly this argument, but as slight modification works for vertex transitive graphs as well: exactly a proportion of $k/n$ of all copies contains a fixed vertex.

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov you mean a vertex transitive graph with clique number $k$ need not have $n$ $k$-cliques?

Comment: It needs (with repetitions!), but you may be unable to find $n$ cliques covering the vertices uniformly. Nevertheless, the orbit of one clique _covers_ the vertices uniformly, and I use that fact.